# Angular 4 Datatable REST Post with data return

Tags: angular, angular-datatables

I'm new to Angular and ran into an issue while trying to retrieve data returned from a REST Post call and show the content in a data table (mat-table). REST Get call works fine. Below are the files and error encountered copied from console (the code compiled fine). I'm not sure what to try next. Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

content of user.model.ts:

```
    export interface User {  
    first_name: string;  
    last_name: string;  
}
```

content of usertable.component.ts:

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';  
import { UserService } from '../../services/user.service';  
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';  
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';  
import {DataSource} from '@angular/cdk/collections';  
import { User } from '../../models/user.model';  
@Component({  
  selector: 'usertable',  
  templateUrl: './usertable.component.html',  
  styleUrls: ['./usertable.component.css']  
})  
export class UsertableComponent implements OnInit {  
  dataSource = new UserDataSource(this.userService);  
  displayedColumns = ['first_name', 'last_name'];  
  constructor(private userService: UserService) { }  
  ngOnInit() {  
  }  
}  
export class UserDataSource extends DataSource<any> {  
  constructor(private userService: UserService) {  
    super();  
  }  
  connect(): Observable<User[]> {  
    return this.userService.getUser();  
  }  
  disconnect() {}  
}
```

content of usertable.component.html

```
    <div class="">  
  <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">  
    <ng-container matColumnDef="first_name">  
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> first_name </mat-header-cell>  
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.first_name}} </mat-cell>  
    </ng-container>  
    <ng-container matColumnDef="last_name">  
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> last_name </mat-header-cell>  
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.last_name}} </mat-cell>  
    </ng-container>  
    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>  
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>  
  </mat-table>  
</div>
```

content of user.service.ts:

```
    import { Injectable }   from '@angular/core';  
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders }   from '@angular/common/http';  
import { Observable }   from 'rxjs/Observable';  
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';  
import { User } from '../models/usertwo.model';  
@Injectable()  
export class UserService {  
  private serviceUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/search';  
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }  
  getUser(): Observable<User[]> {      
    // this get works fine  
    return this.http.get<User[]>(this.serviceUrl);  

    // this post does post data but data returned won't show up in mat-table --- see error detail below  
    // const testObj = {  "first_name": "Jane", "last_name": "Doe" };  
    // const ContentHeaders = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });  
    // return this.http.post(this.serviceUrl, JSON.stringify(testObj), { headers: ContentHeaders });    
  }  
}
```

Error:

```
core.es5.js:1020 ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed  
at DefaultIterableDiffer.diff (core.es5.js:6843)  
at MatTable.CdkTable._renderRowChanges (table.es5.js:633)  
at SafeSubscriber.eval [as _next] (table.es5.js:605)  
at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:240)  
at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:187)  
at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:128)  
at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:92)  
at TakeUntilSubscriber.Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:128)  
at TakeUntilSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:92)  
at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:85)core.es5.js:1020 ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed  
at DefaultIterableDiffer.diff (core.es5.js:6843)  
at MatTable.CdkTable._renderRowChanges (table.es5.js:633)  
at SafeSubscriber.eval [as _next] (table.es5.js:605)  
at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:240)  
at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:187)  
at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:128)  
at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:92)  
at TakeUntilSubscriber.Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:128)  
at TakeUntilSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:92)  
at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:85)
```

REST Post data returned in Postman:

```
  {  
"resultCount": 2,      
"users": [   
    {  
                "first_name": "Bill",  
                "last_name": "Jones"  
    },  
    {  
                "first_name": "Ted",  
                "last_name": "Smith"  
    }     
]
```

}

REST Get data returned in Postman:

```
        {  
                "first_name": "Bill",  
                "last_name": "Jones"  
    },  
    {  
                "first_name": "Ted",  
                "last_name": "Smith"  
    }
```

Comment: Looks like the POST response is not a JSON but a JSON-P. So you have to write your code to handle that differently.

Comment: Can you make a post request in postman and paste the exact output here? I know you have done that in you question but sometimes when trying to fix an issue you may change things without knowing.

Comment: I added a few more changes. Here it is:     {
      "resultCount": 2,
      "users": [
          {
              "id: "1",
              "firstname": "Bill",
              "lastname": "Jones"
          },
          {
              "id: "2",
              "firstname": "Ted",
              "lastname": "Smith"
          }
      ]
  }